# How to create 3D array with filled value along one dimension?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

It's easy to create a 2D array with filled values:

```
import numpy as np

np.full((5, 3), [1])
np.full((5, 3), [1, 2, 3])
```

Then, I wanna create a 3D array with same value for last two dimensions:

```
import numpy as np

np.full((2, 3, 1), [[1], [2]])

'''
# perferred result
[[[1],
  [1],
  [1]]
 [[2],
  [2],
  [2]]]
'''
```

However, I got this error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from the shape (2,1) into shape (2,3,1)
```

Does anyone know the correct way to use `np.full()` for 3D array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to boardcast the value to the desired shape, you require the value in shape `(2, 1, 1)` to match with the input shape `(2, 3, 1)`

```
np.full((2, 3, 1), [[[1]], [[2]]])
```

output:

```
array([[[1],
        [1],
        [1]],

       [[2],
        [2],
        [2]]])
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW, `np.full((2, 3, 1), np.expand_dims([1, 2], axis=(2, 1)))` makes typing easier ;)